# Singular points and residue of $\frac{1}{\cos(z^{-2})}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to find singular points and residue of the function
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{\cos(z^{-2})} \;\;\; z\in \mathbb{C} $$

Can someone help me verify my solution? I found singularities to be points that are of the form $$a = \left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\mathbb{Z}\pi\right)^{-\frac12}$$
Since these are the points where cosine is zero. I gather that this is a rational function, so if f = h / g, this means that $$ h(a) \neq 0, \;\; g(a) = 0, \;\; g'(a) \neq 0$$
and the residue is 
$$ \operatorname{Res}(f,a) = \frac{h(a)}{g'(a)} = \frac{1}{2 \sin(\frac{1}{a^2})\frac{1}{a^3}} = \frac{1}{2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\mathbb{Z}\pi\right)^{\frac32}} $$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isolated singularities of $f$ are those numbers $\omega$ such that $\frac1{\omega^2}=\frac\pi2+n\pi$. And$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=\omega}f(z)=\frac1{2\sin^3\left(\frac1{\omega^2}\right)\frac1{\omega^3}}=\frac{(-1)^n\omega}{2\left(\frac\pi2+n\pi\right)}.$$

Comment: I am unsure how your definition of $\omega$ is different from my singularities $a$. Could you elaborate how you obtained that residue. It's not clear to me how we get anything with $\sin^3$

Comment: It's just that the notation $\left(\frac\pi2+\mathbb Z\pi\right)^{-\frac12}$ is very unclear. On the other hand $\sin\left(\frac\pi2+n\pi\right)=(-1)^n$, and therefore $\sin^3\left(\frac\pi2+n\pi\right)=(-1)^n$ too.

Comment: I understand that reasoning. But then if $\frac1{\omega^2}=\frac\pi2+n\pi$, and $\sin\left(\frac\pi2+n\pi\right)=(-1)^n$, should we not get: $ \operatorname{Res}_{z=\omega} f(z) = \frac{1}{\sin^3 \left( \frac{1}{\omega^2} \right) \frac{1}{\omega^3} } = \frac{1}{ 2(-1)^n \left(\frac{\pi }{2}+n\pi\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.